# How to access a registered workbox queue in my React application

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm using the create-react-app built in service worker for my PWA. I'm using the Queue class from workbox to add failed api calls to the queue. All the registration of the service worker is done in my service-worker.ts file.

My question: How can I access an already registered queue in my React component? I want to display a counter stating the amount of unsycned api calls. It is not clear to me how I can achieve this.

**service-worker.ts**

```
// add failed fetch requests to queue

const queue = new Queue('fetch-requests');

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (!self.navigator.onLine) {
    const promiseChain = fetch(event.request.clone()).catch(() => {
      if (event.request.method === 'POST' || event.request.method === 'PATCH') {
        return queue.pushRequest({ request: event.request });
      }
    });
    event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
  }
});
```

**App.tsx**

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  // how can I access the queue from here and do some stuff with it?
  return <Router />;
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queues are stored in indexedDB as "workbox-background-sync".
So, it's just a matter of querying the store. See example below

```
function getQueuesMeta() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const connection = indexedDB.open("workbox-background-sync")
    const res = []
    
    connection.onsuccess = (event) => {
      const db = event.target.result
    
      try{
        const tx = db.transaction(["requests"])
        const reqIndex = tx.objectStore('requests').index('queueName')
    
        reqIndex.openCursor().onsuccess = (e) => {
          const cursor = e.target.result
          let meta = {}
          if (cursor) {
            meta = {
              // if you got meta, time to get it
              timestamp: cursor.value.timestamp
            }
            if ('undefined' == typeof res[cursor.key]) {
              res[cursor.key] = [meta]
            } else {
              res[cursor.key].push(meta)
            }
            cursor.continue()
          } else {
            resolve(res)
          }
        }
      } catch (error){
        console.log('no ‘request’ objectStore')
        resolve(null)
      }
    }
  })
}
```